# Find indices of a number sequence

Tags: matlab

I have different matrixes looking something like this `matrixExample = [NaN, NaN, 50, 50, 50, 70, 70, 40, 40, 90, 90, 20, 20, 20]`

Is it possible to get the indices of a number sequence in that matrix? I know the matrix contains `70, 70, 40, 40, 90, 90` which is one sequence. Now I want to set it so if the matrix contain a sequence of **`70, 40, 90`** (something I set by myself) I want to get the indices where this sequence begin (70) and end (90). The numbers must come in that set order of numbers but the amount of numbers can differ, `70, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 90, 90, 90` would also count (and so on).

One last example: `matrixExample = [NaN, NaN, 50, 70, 50, 80, 70, 60, 70, 70, 40, 40, 90, 90, 20, 20, 20]`

find where the sequence `70, 40, 90` is and give start and end indices where 70 is the start and 90 is the end.

Help is hugely appreciated!!

Comment: I'd start by writing a function which, using a loop checks if a vector starting at `ii` matches your sequence without letting the numbers match multiple times. Once you have this, I'd extend it to also allow for multiple matches. Finally, I'd ask "what do I want it to do if it there is more than one match sequence, e.g. match longest or match first?"

Comment: There will not be more than one match sequence, therefore I "just" need to find where the sequence start end ends.

Comment: Okay, just the first two points then. To start, something like a small function `matchesAt(ii, v, A)` which checks through `A` starting at `A(ii)` would be quite a simple loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach -

```
search_seq = [70,40,90];
idx = [1 find(diff(matrixExample)~=0)+1 numel(matrixExample)+1];
idx0 = strfind(matrixExample(idx(1:end-1)),search_seq)
start_idx = idx(idx0)
idx1 = idx0+numel(search_seq);
stop_idx = idx(idx1)-1
```

**Sample runs**

Case #1 :

```
>> matrixExample = [NaN, NaN, 50, 50, 50, 70, 70, 40, 40, 90, 90, 20, 20, 20];
start_idx =
     6
stop_idx =
    11
```

Case #2 :

```
>> matrixExample = [NaN, NaN, 50, 70, 50, 80, 70, 60, ...
    70, 70, 40, 40, 90, 90, 20, 20, 20];
start_idx =
     9
stop_idx =
    14
```

Comment: Many thanks, this works great except one thing. If I test it on a very long list, start_idx will be the second last value in that order.

Comment: Another test: matrixExample = [NaN, NaN, 50, 55, 90, 70, 90, 70, 90, 70, 90, 70, 33, 33, 90] will give Start: 4 and End 12.

Comment: Now everything works, I am very grateful for your help! Just one last thing, if it finds more than one sequence that exists in the matrix, it will print it like this: Start: xx   xx, is it possible to limit it to always only show one only?

Comment: @J.Smith Do you mean you want to get the start, stop indices of just the first occurrence of such a `search_seq` in the input matrix?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want.

Comment: @J.Smith In that case, just use `start_idx(0)` and `stop_idx(0)`?